# Question 7F from general topology by Stephen willard?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, alternative-proof, proof-explanation

> Can someone help me with 7F from Willard? In part two :
>
> $\mathbf{7}$**F.** *Functions to and from the plane.*
>
> The facts presented here for the plane will be proved in more generality for product spaces in Section $8$.
>
> If $f$ is a function on any space $X$ to the plane, associated with $f$ we have the coordinate functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, each mapping $X$ to $\Bbb R$. For each $x\in X$, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are the first and second coordinates, respectively, of $f(x)$.
>
> On the other hand, if $g$ is a function from the plane to any space $Y$, for each fixed $x_0\in\Bbb R$ we can define a function $g_{x_0}$ from $\Bbb R$ to $Y$ by $g_{x_0}(y)=g(x_0,y)$. Similarly, if $y_0\in\Bbb R$ is fixed, $h_{y_0}(x)=g(x,y_0)$ defines a function $h_{y_0}$ from $\Bbb R$ to $Y$. We say $g$ is *continuous in* $x$ iff $h_{y_0}$ is continuous for each $y_0\in\Bbb R$ and $g$ is *continuous in* $y$ iff $g_{x_0}$ is continuous for each $x_0\in\Bbb R$.
>
> $2$. If $g:\Bbb R^2\to Y$ is continuous, then it is continuous in both $x$ and $y$.

From S. Willard, *General Topology*; can anyone help?

> - **update**
>
> $f$ is continuous in $x$, iff for all fixed $y$, the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous. But this is just $f$ restricted to $X \times\{y\}$, which is continuous as a restriction of a continuous map.
> Similarly for continuity in $y$.

Is this short proof useful ?

Comment: And how do you prove that the restriction of a continuous map is continuous? But, yes.

Comment: I know that every restriction of continuous is also continuous !

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/206816/21564).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: For any fixed $y_0$, can you write $h_{y_0}(x) = g(x,y_0)$ as a composition of continuous functions?

Comment: can you explain more ? I do not know how I should begin the proof ?

Comment: If you have $g\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, there should be a function $j\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ so that $h_{y_0} = g\circ j$.